# Wait until a delegate method executing in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code:

```
 -(void)serverdata:(NSString *)countryname
{

    NSUserDefaults * defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSString *country = countryname;
            NSString * devicename = @"IOS";
            NSString *device_id = [defaults objectForKey:@"devicetoken"];
            NSLog(@"I AM HERE IN THIS FUNCTION %@",device_id);
           othercode here to send data to server..
}

    if([self checkinternet])
    {
        [self serverdata:@"Mexico"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"manualseg" sender:nil];
    }
```

I want to wait until delegate method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken call's

Thanks indeed it will be a great help.

Comment: Why did you post a new question? You should have clarified your previous question.

Comment: @rmaddy because i think my previous question's wasn't so clear..

Comment: Which is why you should have fixed it instead of posting a new question.

Comment: @rmaddy i am sorry but can you help me sorting this issue? i am really tired!

Comment: @rmaddy '    UIApplication *appDelegatemethod = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegatemethod registerForRemoteNotifications];
    
   ' send's exception in xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can try timer function for this. something like this

```
 func deviceTokenTest(){
        if(devicetoken){ // Make Boolen variable for identify.
            self.loadData()
            println("If that true.. you can proceed")
        }else{
         var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("deviceTokenTest"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        println("Recall the Function Again")
        }
    }
```

In this function. until `devicetoken` true (if device token != nill) function will re call every seconds. hope you can get the idea.